# I cannot spawn new objects in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Alright, so I've been building a small thing in Unity 2D, and it works for the most part, however whenever I attempt to create a script to spawn a copy of the circle prefab, it just doesn't spawn without any error messages.

I've attempted to use Instantiate to spawn them at the button's location, yet no luck.

```
{
    public GameObject circle;
    public Transform circlespawn;
    private bool touched = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if(touched == true)
        {
            Instantiate(circle, circlespawn.position, circlespawn.rotation);
            touched = false;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        touched = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you put this script on? it would need to have a collider, to get the onmousedown

Comment: Oh. So that's why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [BugFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687262/bugfinder) in the comments, he pointed out I simply needed a collider for the onmousedown to work correctly.